# MySQL Pagination - Should sorting be cached?

Tags: mysql, caching, sorting, pagination

I can't find any information on this, so either MySQL handles this and is therefore a non-issue or I'm using the wrong keywords:

If someone wants to sort MySQL results, should I have a cached version of the sort somewhere or should i make my queries with an ORDER BY clause? IS there a better way to do this so that users are not sorting thousands of rows every time they change the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [create an index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on the column that wish to order by.

See the documentation [`ORDER BY` Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html) for when MySQL can use an index to improve the performance of a query with `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an index "with a sort criteria" on the column that you want to sort.

This is the syntax to create mysql index:

```
CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [index_type]

index_col_name:
    col_name [(length)] [ASC | DESC]
```

So, if you usually retrieve some data sorted by `some_column` ordered `DESC`, you should:

```
CREATE INDEX my_index ON my_table (some_column DESC)
```